# TextView Id keeps calling on null no matter what way I try to change its content

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I have a `TabLayout` with 3 fragments inside. Fragment 0 contains details, 1 is a description and 2 is location.

But no matter how I try to call the fragment Ids inside my `carDetailsActivity` or I try to pass the value from the activity to the fragments it keeps calling on null and giving the following result:
Tab Fragment

[image]

Now I tried multiple ways one of them to `Bundle` the text value from the activity to the fragment but I still got null "IllegaleStateException". (which was the best option to my knowledge) but it still didnt work.

This is how I want it to look (the design is in arabic):

[image]

Here is my Activity where im calling them at the moment but I just get empty strings (had to give them ? because the app kept crashing if I didnt):

```
class CarDetailsActivity : BaseActivity() {
    val TAG = "CarDetailsActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val car = intent.extras!!.getParcelable<Car>(DETAILS_TRANSFER) as Car
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_details)
        activateToolbar(true)

        carPriceDetails?.text = car.price.toString()
        carDate?.text = car.date
        carCategory?.text = car.category
        carModel?.text = car.brandModel
        carYear?.text = car.modelYear
        carKilometer?.text = car.kilometer.toString()
        carGear?.text = car.gearType
        carFuel?.text = car.fuelType

        val fragmentAdapter = FragmentCarInfo(supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = fragmentAdapter

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)


        carBrand.text = car.brand
        carModel.text = car.brandModel
        carYear.text = car.modelYear


        Picasso.with(this).load(car.image)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_cars)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cars)
            .into(carImage)

    }
}
```

Here is the main `Fragment` that contains that layout that contains the details:

```
class InfoFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_details_info, container, false)
    }
}
```

I have asked this similar question before but it was'nt clear enough so I hope this was a better way to post my problem.

**-EDIT**
My tabLayout viewPager uses this

```
class FragmentCarInfo (fm : FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm){

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0-> {
                InfoFragment()
            }
            1 -> {
                AboutFragment()
            }
            else -> {
                return LocationFragment()
            }

        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when (position) {
            0-> "Details"
            1-> "About"
            else -> {
                return "Locations"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the data you are passing? It seems like the activity is receiving data? from where?

Comment: A car class where im fetching data but thats working fine I only have an issue with the display of content in those textviews

Comment: @RandomCoder Can you post the code for the Fragment Adapter? So far I have noticed some issues with your code, but I will answer them once you show us the adapter code so I can understand better. :)

Comment: I edited my code @M'aiqtheCoder

Comment: @RandomCoder Super, in a few minutes I will come back with an answer

Comment: Take your time. Thank you so much! :) @M'aiqtheCoder

Comment: I can not understand what you want to do in your fragments. It seems all UI components are in your activity, not in `InfoFragment`、`AboutFragment`、`LocationFragment`.
If you want fetch `car` data in fragment, maybe you can try pass it into fragment's argument by `setArguments()`, and call `getArguments()` in fragment to fetch `car`.

Comment: @Hababa I tried but I still got an illegalstateexception and my app crashed at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend ditching the old and nasty TabLayout and switch to the new ViewPager2 instead of the old ViewPager. UI wise, instead of the TabLayout, create custom 3 buttons inside a LinearLayout or ConstraintLayout.

Now, in your case I would use the ViewPager2 with a FragmentStateAdapter because it was designed to work well with Fragments and you can create as many of them as you need. I even had a project where I had 80 fragments created with a FragmentStateAdapter.

Second of all, you need a newInstance constructor for your fragments as a safe pattern. If you don't use that, you might get some exceptions later in your app, but other than that you will also use the function to pass your data to each fragment.

Here is how I do it:

```
class FragmentStateAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    car: Car
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> InfoFragment.newInstance(car)
            1 -> AboutFragment.newInstance(car)
            else -> LocationFragment.newInstance(car)
    }
}
```

Basically I am passing your car object (presuming it's the only data object that needs to reach the fragments) as a parameter to the FragmentStateAdapter, locking the itemCount to 3 because you have 3 fragments and then returning an instance of each fragment in the override method createFragment(). Now, creating the instance functions:

```
class InfoFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        private const val BUNDLE_KEY = "car_object"

        fun newInstance(car: Car) = InfoFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable<Car>(BUNDLE_KEY, car)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_details_info, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
         val car = arguments.getParcelable<Car>(BUNDLE_KEY)
    }
}
```

And this is how you get your car object inside your fragments. Basically in the newInstance() function you create a new instance of your fragment and pass data to it via bundle. Inside your activity this is how you initialise your adapter:

```
val adapter = FragmentStateAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle, car)
```

Now, about the replacement for the tab view, do a custom LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.333"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:text="Details"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.333"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:text="About"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.333"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:paddingBottom="14dp"
        android:text="Locations"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

and then set the initial color of the buttons after your own preference with `android:background="#COLOR_OR_CHOICE"`

In activity, add the three buttons in an ArrayList of buttons and use this listener on the viewPager2:

```
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
 // here, get the position of the viewPager2 and change the color of the current button using the arrayList index that matches the viewPager2 position.
```

})

Then, on every button's click listener, do viewPager2.setCurrentItem(position_you_want_to_go_to, true) where true is a check for a smooth scroll.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got an issue at FragmentStateAdapter when I use "car" in newInstance it says unresolved, and at val adapter when I call my viewpager.adapter = adapter I get "required: PagerAdapter?, found: FragmentStateAdapter"

Comment: first issue: instead of class FragmentStateAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    car: Car
)  write class FragmentStateAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    private val car: Car
) 

Second issue: make sure to use ViewPager2 library https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2 it is far superior than the standard library

Comment: Also, lines like  carPriceDetails?.text = car.price.toString()
        carDate?.text = car.date
        carCategory?.text = car.category should stay inside the fragments, not activity

Comment: I changed my viewpager to the one you recommended but do you mind showing an example on how I can connect the 3 buttons I create to the viewpager2 instead of the tablayout? also would that effect the design by any chance? like the tab (if selected) has a purple background etc would that effect remain with the buttons?

Comment: The data is now being passed so thank you so much, just the viewpager2 thing left if you can help me with that about the buttons

Comment: because when I slide through the next pages it keeps repeating InfoFragment through the 3 visible pages

Comment: @RandomCoder I will update my answer with the CustomTabLayout in a few minutes

Comment: @RandomCoder also, do you want transition when swiching fragments? Like animation and left / right scroll using swipe gestures?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be assigning the values to the fields in your fragment?

Comment: Thats what I meant when i said I tried to "Bundle" my values from the activity to the fragments but it still didnt work

Comment: Okay, I'm not too familiar with kotlin but it looks to me you have all your ui components in your main activity. What I was saying is, you should probably have your components (textviews) inside each fragment and then get and set the data from there. You said you were getting empty strings before for the results and you had go add the '?' To the fields to get rid of the error. If I'm not mistaken, the ? In kotlin just makes an object nullable so you are still getting no data